# Automatic Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap tabs to automatically tab but when a tab is clicked i want the tabbing to pause for a certain amount of time or stop completely.  Here is the piece of javascript i am using.

```
    var timer = null, 
    interval = 1000,
    value = 0;

$("#start").click(function() {
  if (timer !== null) return;
  timer = setInterval(function () {
      value = value+1;
      $("#input").val(value);
  }, interval); 
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null
});
```

Comment: Will be difficult to help you without understanding where it get stuck or fail. Might help, if you can create a fiddle or give us more inputs.

Comment: @Pallab Here is a sample fiddle that I made: http://jsfiddle.net/LegendDrummer/ahLyZ/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have not already solved it ... here is your fiddle you can check.

```
// Tab click event handler
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stop the cycle
    clearInterval(tabCycle);
    // Show the clicked tabs associated tab-pane
    $(this).tab('show');
    // Start the cycle again in a predefined amount of time
    setTimeout(function () {
        //tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);
    }, 15000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahLyZ/1/

Comment: I just noticed that tabChange & tabCycle are missing from your answer, although they are present in your jsfiddle example. I think if it is possible for you to update your answer with the rest of the code, that will be helpful for others (in case jsfiddle is down for maintenance, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

you can pause tabbing with the help of below code

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
            //pause here               
    })
```

> **show:** This event fires on tab show, **but before the new tab has been shown**...
>   --http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 1):

I have added the clock to the Pallab's code. So that even if different tabs are clicked before the timeout period which is 10 seconds in my case the current tab will be shown for 10 seconds and tabs will automatically tab after 5 seconds. I am a beginner so please bear with my coding.

You have to click 2 or more tabs , one tab at at a time , in less than 10 seconds

// Tab-Pane change function

```
tabChange = function(){
    var tabs = $('.nav-tabs > li');
    var active = tabs.filter('.active');
    var next = active.next('li').length? active.next('li').find('a') : tabs.filter(':first-child').find('a');
    // Use the Bootsrap tab show method
    next.tab('show');
}    // Tab Cycle function
function settabchnge () {
    //alert("in set tab");
tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);
}

settabchnge();

function cleartabchange () {
    clearInterval(tabCycle);
}
```

$(function(){

```
    var counterofclock = 1;
    var counterofmoreclicks = 1; 
    var clicked = false;
    var sec = 0;
    function startClock() {
        if (clicked === false) {
            clock = setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
            clicked = true;
        }else if (clicked === true) {
        }
    }       
    function stopWatch() {
            sec++;
    }
    function stopClock() {
            window.clearInterval(clock);
            sec = 0;
            clicked = false;
    }
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e) {
        if(counterofclock === 1){
            startClock();
            counterofclock = 2;
        }else {
            stopClock();
            startClock();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stop the cycle
        if (counterofmoreclicks == 2 && sec < 11){
            clearTimeout(starttabchnage);
        }
        counterofmoreclicks = 2;
        clearInterval(tabCycle);
        // Show the clicked tabs associated tab-pane
        $(this).tab('show')
        // Start the cycle again in a predefined amount of time
        starttabchnage = setTimeout(function(){ settabchnge();}, 10000);
    });


})
```